# silent installation when there is space in the folder name

Tags: installation

I want to run silent setup from cmd, this works fine:

```
C:\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder>setup /s /v/qn /vINSTALLDIR="D:\targetFolder"
```

but when I try to install to target folder with spaces ike `D:\target Folder` it doesn't work.

I tried

```
C:\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder>setup /s /v"/qn /vINSTALLDIR="D:\target Folder""
```

but it doesn't do nothing

Comment: What does "it doesn't do nothing" mean?  Does it install but to the wrong directory?  Does it fail to install?  Does it display any errors?

Comment: it means nothing

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?157599-Spaces-in-INSTALLDIR-s-value-erroring-out-Basic-MSI-Project), Istead of this command:

```
C:\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder>setup /s /v/qn /vINSTALLDIR="D:\targetFolder"
```

Give this a try:

```
C:\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder>setup /s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"D:\target Folder\""
```